# Detect whether iPad supports sim card programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Currently, I have an app that shows the 3G data / Wifi used by the user since the last reboot.
What I want to do is, if the app is running on an iPad which doesn’t support SIM card, I want to hide certain statistics shown to the user.

Is it somehow possible to detect whether the current iOS device supports a sim card or not?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you cannot detect if the SIM card is installed. You can only determine if a WWAN connection is available using [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) or you can use [CTCarrier](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coretelephony/ctcarrier#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009596-CH1-SW1)

```
@import CoreTelephony;

-(BOOL)hasCellularCoverage
{
    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
    CTCarrier *carrier = [networkInfo subscriberCellularProvider];


    if (!carrier.isoCountryCode) {
        NSLog(@"No sim present Or No cellular coverage or phone is on airplane mode.");
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```